# In a Qt signal-slot programm,The slot function was not executed after sent

Tags: c++, qt, rpc, signals-slots, data-distribution-service

I am writing an RPC-like program that uses the Qt signal slot, when using a client program to call the server, a function is executed, and I need to print the value of this function on the QtableWidget, so I use `emit` to transmit signals in this function, but I find that the slot function is not executed. This seems to be related to multithreading.

update: I found that I made a mess of the code, here to simplify.
I use a static class method to emit a signal so the code looks a little bit tricky.

```
// service.cpp file
#include "service.h"
multipleService* multipleService::getInstance = nullptr;
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
multipleService::multipleService() {
    getInstance = this; // for static method to emit signal
    bool ok = connect(this, &multipleService::internalMessageOutput, this, &multipleService::messageOutputFunc, Qt::AutoConnection);
}
// implement service
void multipleService::AddService(ServiceType::Request& request, ServiceType::Response& response) {
// do some stuff ... get response
emit getInstance->internalMessageOutput(QString(response));
}
void multipleService::messageOutputFunc(QString msg) {
    emit getInstance->messageOutput(msg);
}
```

```
// service.h file
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
// some declarations
class multipleService :public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    multipleService();
    ~multipleService();
    static void AddService(ServiceType::Request& request, ServiceType::Response& response);
    void messageOutputFunc(QString);
private:
    static multipleService* getInstance;
signals:
    void messageOutput(QString);
    void internalMessageOutput(QString);
};
```

And in the `mainwindow.cpp` file, I use `create_service` to behave like a server in RPC. And this actually works fine. once `emit getInstance->internalMessageOutput(QString(response));` executes,the signal func executes.

```
//mainwindow.cpp in main thread
multipleService* s = new multipleService();
connect(s, &multipleService::messageOutput, this, &serviceThread::outputMessage);
auto service = node.create_service<ServiceType>(service_name, multipleService::AddService, qoS);
```

But I want to create a multithread so I changed the code like

```
// mainwindow.cpp file in main thread
QThread* thread = new QThread; //create a thread 
serviceThread* myThread = new serviceThread(this);// create a class which derives from QObject and move it to the thread
//connect start signal with a lambda func
connect(thread, &QThread::started, myThread, [&myThread, SERVICE_NAME]() 
{  std::string a = SERVICE_NAME;
   char* AddServiceName = (char*)a.data();
   myThread->createService("NODE", AddServiceName, 10);
});
// start a thread and this will call the slot func
thread->start();
myThread->moveToThread(thread);
```

I create a `serviceThread.cpp` and `new serviceThread` and move it to a thread to support multithread but `emit getInstance->internalMessageOutput(QString(response))`,the slot func doesn't execute.

```
//serviceThread.cpp file 
void serviceThread::createService(const char* nodeName, const char* service_name, int historyDepth) {
// do some declaration
   multipleService* s = new multipleService();
   connect(s, &multipleService::messageOutput, this, 
&serviceThread::outputMessage);
auto service = node.create_service<ServiceType>(service_name, 
   multipleService::AddService, qos);
if (service) {
        service->start();
}
else {
    // error
    return;
}
    while (true)
    {  // 
        if (QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested())
        {
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried to change the connect type to `Qt::QueuedConnection` and this also failed. I also set a breakpoint on the line and it literally executed.

**update**: OK,I find something wrong with the `while` loop in the multithread, I use `QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 10);` in the loop to temporirally solve this problem. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: ***This seems to be related to multithreading?*** If it is related to multithreading you can force `Qt::QueuedConnection` in the connect to fix the problem / force the slot to execute in the proper thread.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint on this line to see if its ever executed: `emit getInstance->messageOutput(msg);`

Comment: To keep your design clean, consider writing it so that you only ever do `emit this->signal();`. Otherwise, if you are unsure of what you are doing, you have probably created mess.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used  `Qt::QueuedConnection`  in the connect and I did set a breakpoint and the line `emit getInstance->messageOutput(msg);`  was executed.

Comment: sorry, that's an error. I deleted that line of code @Swift-FridayPie

Comment: You should show declaration of `serviceThread` type. My look of it you made an ummovable object.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of problems I see right away is `mainwindow.cpp` code:

```
QThread* thread = new QThread; //create a thread 
serviceThread* myThread = new serviceThread(this);// create a class which derives 
...
myThread->moveToThread(thread); // this will silently fail.
```

If you look up documention on website, you must pay attention, they mentioned that. You *can't* move a parented `QObject` and you cannot move a `QWidget` at all. Since `serviceThread` is a `QObject`, `myThread` cannot be moved - it is parented to main window now, which is part of main thread.

My usual approach to this is

- have an `QObject`-derived class, let's call it `Manager`,
- move `Manager` to the worker thread,
- connecting appropriate signals of `QThread` to `Manager`s slots.
- `Manager` would create the rest of objects
- and act as a proxy and a parent to his children.

Code for an old project, redacted.. sorry for Qt4 style `connect()`

```
void QApp::startThreads()
{
    // Just basic thread is enough here
    netThread = new QThread(this); 
    manager = new Manager();
    
    // IMPORTANT: Manager does not have a parent
    // 
    // 1.moveToThread first
    //
    manager->moveToThread(netThread); 
    //
    // 2. connect later. moveToThread breaks it.
    //
    // run main function when thread started
    connect(netThread, SIGNAL(started()), manager, SLOT(start()));
    // delete everything when we stop thread. 
    connect(netThread, SIGNAL(finished()), manager, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    // Something Manager-specific, just for an example
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(receivedData()), this, SLOT(updateAll()) );
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(receivedStatus()), ConData, SLOT(onReceive()));

    netThread->start();
}
```

What `Manager::start` does:

```
void Manager::start()
{
   // 1. create children objects
   // 2. connect signals
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Because I want to use `mainwindow`, such as use `QMessageBox` in the serviceThread, I passed `mainwindow`  to serviceThread  whose construct method is `serviceThread::serviceThread(QWidget* parentWidget)
{
 this->parentWidget = parentWidget;
};`.I didn't set the `parent`  attribute. So there is no error like cannot move objects with a parent

Comment: @Sqh ah, so that's just an unfortunate breach of LSP (least surprise principle). It actually doesn't matter where you parent thread (and why you don't parent it here? You can parent it to window or to the app). That affects only its scope of life. Unparented thread would live until program dies (after your `QApplication` instance destructor) which might be desired behaviour in _some_ cases but may cause issues. Thing is you're connecting before moving